# Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular-cli

I have created a angular project with  Angular CLI: 1.6.3 Node: 9.4.0
OS: linux x64 version. But when want to run my angular app with command ng serve then fetch this error

> Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'.

Answer (score 102):

Try the following steps,

**Step 1:**

`npm update -g @angular/cli`

**Step 2:**

Edit your package.json changing the line

**`"@angular/cli": "1.6.0",`**

**to**

**`"@angular/cli": "^1.6.0"`**,

**STEP 3:**

**`npm update`**

Refer the [`steps`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307)

Comment: This helped me, +1 for that. But could you also add information on what these are solving?

Comment: I had to clear out node_modules, and do a fresh install using npm install, after updating the version to "^1.6.0".

Comment: I would give +1 if there'd be any explanation as to the cause of this. Freaking ridiculous to get compilation error on a fresh new project...

Comment: im not sure what explanation to provide! the commands are self explanatory and it was a bug which is fixed afaik

Answer (score 28):

try this out

`npm install @angular-devkit/core --save-dev`

https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/256

try to update your angular cli

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307

Answer (score 26):

**Step1:** Edit your package.json changing the line

```
@angular/cli": "1.6.4"
```

to

```
@angular/cli": "^1.6.4"
```

**Step2:**

```
npm update -g @angular/cli
```

**Step3:**

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

I was facing the exact same problem. These three did the tasks for me. You may like to see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307

Comment: I used  "npm update -g @angular/cli@latest" then "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest", after that, the error disappear

Comment: Sorry, mistakes made, the command I actually used was "npm install -g @angular/cli@latest" then "npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"

Answer (score 24):

This can happen on different versions on angular-cli.
You can install it manually with

```
 npm i -D @angular-devkit/core
```

> -D is shortcut to --save-dev

Or try the latest version of angular cli

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: This combined with running npm install again, worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

package.json, change to "@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",

```
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "^1.6.5",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
```

Important, the version could be vary depends on what time.

You really should run

```
 npm update -g @angular/cli
```

first, to get version, my is 1.6.5

What does the "^" do?

```
 ~1.0.2 means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest patch version such as 1.0.4. 

  ^1.0.2 means to install version 1.0.2 or the latest minor or patch version such as 1.1.0.
```

last, run this

```
   npm update
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

In the project folder, to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by deleting package-lock.json and the node_modules folder. After that run "npm install" and start the application again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

First,

Delete the `node_modules` folder

Run `npm install`

And add devkit to your dev dependancies with `npm i -D @angular-devkit/core`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: delete package-lock.json
Step 2: npm update -g @angular/cli
Step 3: update @angular/cli new version in package.json
Step 4: npm install

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I only installed my angular/cli using:
`npm install -g @angular/cli@1.5.2`
And I started getting this error.

**Solution:**
If your version is global and
If you don't mind the version of your **angular/cli** then type:
`npm update -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 0):

for me adding @angular-devkit/core solved the issue

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/core
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error after updating some packages.

In my *package.json* I had the most current '@angular-devkit/core'

Using the **standard solution** to many problems:

```
rm -R node_modules/
npm install
```

And I updated the @angular/cli

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

and finally:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 0):

Only change `"@angular/cli": "1.6.4",` to `"@angular/cli": "^1.6.4",` and update npm with: `npm update`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this with `@angular-devkit/architect` package

```
npm i -D @angular-devkit/architect
```