# "Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks' " on updating angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When updating angular cli in project root folder I run into an error.

Running this command: `ng update @angular/cli`

returns the following error

```
Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'
Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'
```

I tried removing node modules file then run npm install, also tried running `npm i @angular-devkit/schematics` but the error persists.

local CLI version: 1.7.4, global CLI version: 7.3.7

Comment: What do you get if you run `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest ` ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307#issuecomment-359264655

Comment: @Delena Malan Running `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` successfully upgraded local cli to version **7.3.7**. However I still needed to run `ng update @angular/cli` to migrate workspace configuration to angular.json format as I am updating the project from angular 5.0 to angular 7.2. This time the error didn't reoccur, got a different error **Unknown option: '--sourcemap'**. Changing sourceMap configuration in angular.json fixed it, thus I've successfully updated my project. I appreciate your assistance, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394003/cannot-find-module-angular-devkit-core)

Answer (score 3):

Run `npm update -g @angular/cli` then add `'^'` before the version clousre like follows

```
"@angular/cli": "^1.7.4"
```

Delete `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` directory. Then run `npm i` or use `npm update` to update your workspace.