# Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting the below mentioned error when I execute **ng s --open** command:

> Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli' Error: Cannot find module
> '@angular/compiler-cli'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:655:15)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:25)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
> at Object. (G:\Front-End\angular\rapydly\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:12:24)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
> at Object. (G:\Front-End\angular\rapydly\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:13:10)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:816:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:672:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:604:3)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)
> at Object. (G:\Front-End\angular\rapydly\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js:4:19)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:805:30)

This is my **package.json** file:

```
{
  "name": "rapid",
  "version": "1.1.9",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "^4.0.0",
    "@dvsl/zoomcharts": "^1.18.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/c3": "^0.6.0",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.8.1",
    "angular-confirmation-popover": "^4.2.0",
    "angular-datatables": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-tag-input": "^1.2.3",
    "angular2-toaster": "^6.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.271.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.0.3",
    "c3": "^0.6.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.18",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.3.4",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.1.9",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^4.2.1",
    "ng2-table": "^1.3.2",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.1.6",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.1.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-popover": "0.0.16",
    "ngx-spinner": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^2.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Can some one guide me as to what the issue is to get the error? I am working on the windows platform. I uninstalled the previous node version and installed the new version. Still it's giving the same error.

Comment: Have you checked the following issue? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4725  Seems the same problem.

Comment: Did you update your `cli` version recently?

Comment: yes i updated it recently @neo

Comment: @Santhosh yes I thought so. I see you have resolved the issue by seeing your answer. Anyways have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498111/error-cannot-find-module-angular-devkit-schematics-tasks-on-updating-angu/55501347#55501347). And It's been a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9307).

Comment: i actually tried deleting the node module and executed **npm install** . and '^' was there in my package.json but dont know it was throwing the same error. @neo

Comment: @Santhosh deleting `node_modules` is just an assurance. Did you check the links I provided?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By executing the `npm i @angular/compiler-cli` everything is again working perfectly.

Answer (score 12):

Just follow steps  ->

1. Delete your node_modules folder manually or **rm -r node_modules**
2. Clean npm cache ->  **npm cache clean**
3. Install npm by running **npm install**

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when I was going to run my angular 7 application first time which was cloned from azure devops repository. Just executed the following command on node terminal in visual studio code and error was solved.

```
npm i @angular/compiler-cli
```