# Angular project error with ng serve Cannot find module '@ angular-devkit / core'

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I have the global version 1.5.0 of angular / cli, I have downloaded the visual studio code and I have created a project with the command "ng new projectCheckBox", then I have done an ng serve and visual studio code throws me the following error

```
E: \ Projects \ AngularCode \ projectCheckBox> ng serve
module.js: 487
 throw err;
 ^

Error: Cannot find module '@ angular-devkit / core'
 at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js: 485: 15)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js: 437: 25)
 at Module.require (module.js: 513: 17)
 at require (internal / module.js: 11:18)
 at Object. <anonymous> (E: \ Projects \ AngularCode \ projectCheckBox \ node_modules \ @ angular-devkit \ schematics \ src \ tree \ virtual.js: 10:16)
 at Module._compile (module.js: 569: 30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js: 580: 10)
 at Module.load (module.js: 503: 32)
 at tryModuleLoad (module.js: 466: 12)
 at Function.Module._load (module.js: 458: 3)
```

I'm missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/core'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394003/cannot-find-module-angular-devkit-core)

Answer (score 5):

Are you using **Node Package Manager**?
If so, you might wanna run:

```
npm install
```

(to install all missing packages) or

```
npm update -g @angular/cli
```

(to update your cli (globally))

Answer (score 3):

Lea is right!
Can use this :

```
npm update -g @angular/cli
```

and edit your package.json changing the line
"@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
to
"@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",

after use :

```
npm update
```

But command : `npm update -g @angular/cli` should be enough :) .